# ASP.NET dynamic creation of text box using asp:Panel and access the text box using FindControl

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I am using ASP `Panel` to dynamically create text boxes on button click. The code i am using is as below,

```
<asp:TextBox ID="text_number" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="button1" runat="server" OnClick="button1_Click"></asp:Button>
<asp:Panel ID="mypanel" runat="server"></asp:Panel>
<asp:Button ID="button2" runat="server" OnClick="button2_Click"></asp:Button>


protected void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int n = Convert.ToInt32(text_number.Text);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        TextBox MyTextBox = new TextBox();
        MyTextBox.ID = "newtext_" + (i + 1);
        mypanel.Controls.Add(MyTextBox);
        MyTextBox.CssClass = "textblock";
        Literal lit = new Literal();
        lit.Text = "<br />";
        mypanel.Controls.Add(lit);
    }
}
```

After i click on button1 the text boxes are created and then i enter values to the text boxes and click on button2. When clicking button2 all values from text boxes should be read and stored in list behind C#. The code i am using is as below,

```
protected void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int n = Convert.ToInt32(text_number.Text);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        TextBox control = (TextBox) FindControl("newtext_" + (i+1));
        mylist.Add(control.Text);
    }
}
```

But whenever i click on the button2, all the text boxes i added in the panel disappear from the web page and also i get the null object reference error in the FindControl. I can understand that all the text box controls within the panel gets cleared when pressing the button2 and this is the reason they disappear in web page and also the reason for getting null object error. what is the problem here? is there any other way to dynamically create 'n' text boxes on button click and then fetch the values from them on second button click without any issues like this?

Answer (score 0):

Because you are creating Controls dynamically, you need to recerate them on every Page Load otherwise the Controls and their content will be lost.

What you need to do is store the number of TextBoxes into a `Session` or `ViewState` and recreate them.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //check if the viewstate exists and if so, build the controls
    if (ViewState["boxCount"] != null)
    {
        buildControls(Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["boxCount"]));
    }
}

protected void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //adding controls moved outside the button click in it's own method
    try
    {
        buildControls(Convert.ToInt32(text_number.Text));
    }
    catch
    {
    }
}

protected void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //check if the viewstate exists and if so, build the controls
    if (ViewState["boxCount"] != null)
    {
        int n = Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["boxCount"]);

        //loop al controls count stored in the viewstate
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            TextBox control = FindControl("newtext_" + i) as TextBox;
            mylist.Add(control.Text);
        }
    }
}

private void buildControls(int n)
{
    //clear the panel of old controls
    mypanel.Controls.Clear();

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        TextBox MyTextBox = new TextBox();
        MyTextBox.ID = "newtext_" + i;
        MyTextBox.CssClass = "textblock";
        mypanel.Controls.Add(MyTextBox);

        Literal lit = new Literal();
        lit.Text = "<br />";
        mypanel.Controls.Add(lit);
    }

    //save the control count into a viewstate
    ViewState["boxCount"] = n;
}
```